# Google Event Tracking Breaking Fancybox Plugin

Tags: jquery, google-analytics, fancybox, event-tracking

I have a problem with a recent site I developed: http://www.thankstofarmers.org/

It was all working fine until last night, on day three of it's launch when I decided to start tracking external links clicked with Google Event Tracking. As the main call to action of our website is to go to an external website and signup, it's an important thing for us to monitor.

Furthermore, linking to an external website for a page's main CTA seems a little amateur, so I wanted to figure out a way of keeping the visitors on our page, whilst being able to sign in and pledge thanks through the external website http://www.thanksto.com/campaign/thanks-to-farmers . I concluded that the best (albeit still far from perfect) resolution in the timeframe would be to do it through the beautiful fancybox plugin.

This was all working fine, until the time that I wanted to attach these event trackers on top of the clicks as well as the lightbox. The fancybox plugin then started failing. It starts to load on click, but then links to the thanksto.com/ website away from the page and not within the lightbox like it used to. Have you any idea why this might be and more to the point, any idea how I might go about resolving the problem?

For the time being I have left the code in the website, because at this stage it is more important that we are able to track the links clicked, than keep the users on the page. But also so you clever cats can see what is going on behind the scenes if needed.

By clicking on any of the "show your thanks" CTA buttons on the thankstofarmers website - URL in the first paragraph (stack-overflow would not allow me more than 2 links per post) will bring up the effect that I am talking about.

Any help with this would be absolutely AMAZING!

Thank you, Rufus.

P.s. Don't forget to thank farmers in the process - it will also give you a chance to trawl one of the buggiest, slowest websites that I have ever come across. (Another reason for the lightbox :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your event tracking script is redirecting visitors:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function recordOutboundLink(link, category, action) {
    _gat._getTrackerByName()._trackEvent(category, action);
    setTimeout('document.location = "' + link.href + '"', 100);
  }
</script>
```

See this `setTimeout` function? it has a redirect statement with a 100ms delay. Instead of calling this `recordOtboundLink` function, use native GA syntax:

`<a href="#" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', category, action, optional_label, optional_value, optional_noninteraction]);">link text</a>`

So in your case that would be smth like

`<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.thanksto.com/campaign/thanks-to-farmers" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'http://www.thanksto.com/campaign/thanks-to-farmers', 'Large Home CTA', 'thanksto.com']);return false;">link text</a>`

Refer to [GA tracking guide](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html) or this [conversion university tutorial](http://services.google.com/analytics/breeze/en/v5/et_vpsv22_ad1_2/)  (from p.8) for details.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :) That conversion university tutorial will be immensely helpful for the future as well! Regards. Rufus